# Error on copying CreationDate in Powershell: .CreationTime was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I try to copy the dates of the original file after converting them with ffmpeg, but it gives me following error: ".CreationTime was unexpected at this time".

Script:

```
set /A g=5
set /A crf=20
set encoding=x265
set targetFolder=.\converted

for %%f in (.\*.mp4) do (
    echo "fullname: %%f"
    echo "name: %%~nf"
    ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vcodec "lib%encoding%" -crf %crf% -g %g% "%targetFolder%\%%~nf.crf%crf%.%encoding%.mp4"
    $(Get-Item "%targetFolder%\%%~nf.crf%crf%.%encoding%.mp4").CreationTime=(Get-Item "%%f").CreationTime
    $(Get-Item "%targetFolder%\%%~nf.crf%crf%.%encoding%.mp4").LastWriteTime=(Get-Item "%%f").LastWriteTime
    $(Get-Item "%targetFolder%\%%~nf.crf%crf%.%encoding%.mp4").LastAccessTime=(Get-Item "%%f").LastAccessTime
)
```

Note: outside the loop the command works:

```
$(Get-Item ".\converted\VID_20200712_103210.crf20.x265.mp4").CreationTime=(Get-Item ".\VID_20200712_103210.mp4").CreationTime
```

Comment: You're trying to embed PowerShell commands in a batch file, which cannot work. To execute PowerShell commands, you must call via [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI or [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI.

Comment: Preferably, simply write all your code as a PowerShell script (`*.ps1` file) instead of a batch file (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`).

Comment: I am executing the script within powershell.exe

Comment: Invoking a _batch file_ in PowerShell executes it via a `cmd.exe` _child process_, and that child process knows nothing about PowerShell's commands or syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated my script to a PowerShell script and it now works:

```
$g=5
$crf=20
$encoding="x265"
$targetFolder=".\converted"

foreach ($f in (Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.mp4")) {
    Write-Host "fullname: $f"
    Write-Host "name: $($f.BaseName)"
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec "lib$encoding" -crf $crf -g $g "$($targetFolder)\$($f.BaseName).crf$crf.$encoding.mp4"
    (Get-Item "$($targetFolder)\$($f.BaseName).crf$crf.$encoding.mp4").CreationTime=(Get-Item $f).CreationTime
    (Get-Item "$($targetFolder)\$($f.BaseName).crf$crf.$encoding.mp4").LastWriteTime=(Get-Item $f).LastWriteTime
    (Get-Item "$($targetFolder)\$($f.BaseName).crf$crf.$encoding.mp4").LastAccessTime=(Get-Item $f).LastAccessTime
}
```

Comment:  You can streamline the commands after the `ffmpeg` calls as follows:     `$target = Get-Item -LiteralPath "$($targetFolder)\$($f.BaseName).crf$crf.$encoding.mp4";
    foreach ($prop in 'CreationTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'LastAccessTime') {
      $target.$prop = $f.$prop
    }`